# Char[] values not being printed?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm adding the following to my char[]

```
 int index = 0;
 char i = '5';
 char q = '7';
 char val = (i - '0') + (q - '0');
 array[index] = val;
 ++index;
```

If I print out `val` once the value has been assigned it prints out the value as `2` (as it should). However, if I then print out my char array like so.. `printf("%.*s\n",index,array);` Nothing prints but empty space. Why is this happening?

Comment: This is the kind of question that would greatly be benefited if you expanded your code to a full program we can just copy and paste in order to compile and run,

Comment: ??  I make val to be 0x12 - a form feed character.

Comment: @MartinJames not `0x12` but decimal `12`.

Comment: OK, yes, oops, a form-feed anyway, that twelvy thing on my ASCII chart.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't added '0' back to the number you put into the array (nor have you added a NUL terminator), so it's being printed out as whatever character happens to have the value `12` in the character set (and possibly code page) you're using (followed by whatever other contents memory may contain up until the next byte that happens to contain a zero).

In the ASCII character set (and derivatives such as Unicode) character 12 is a Form Feed character. If you fed it to a printer that understood ASCII, it would probably eject that page so text after it was printed on the next page. On screen, however, there's usually not much meaning to give to it, so it'll typically show up as a blank (or possibly some special character like a smiley face or something).

Answer (score 1):

Each ASCII character has an integer value. When printing a character, the underlaying system checks the value of `char` variable and prints the corresponding ASCII character. The value itself is not printed. See [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) for reference.

```c
char var = '7'; // var's value is actually 55.
char other = 55; // This is same as '7'
```

When calculating the sum of two *digit* characters, in your case '5' and '7', you have to subtract character '0' from them to convert '5' and '7' to numbers 5 and 7.

```c
char first = '5' - '0'; // Is actually 53 - 48 = 5
char second = '7' - '0'; // Is actually 55 - 48 = 7
char result = first + second; // 5 + 7 = 12

// When you print result, you will not see "12" printed. Instead you see a form feed special character.

char test = '5' + '7'; // 53 + 55 = 108, which is letter 'l'
```

You have to convert the value of `char` to string to print the actual value. You can convert with `itoa()`.

```c
char result = ('5' - '0') + ('7' - '0');
char buf[5];
memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));

itoa((int)result, buf, 10);
printf("%s\n", buf);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are telling `printf` that it's a string, but values are not printable ASCII values.

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming you meant it prints out the value `12`, that means you're trying to print character number `12` in the ASCII character set. That character (http://www.asciitable.com/) is a non-printable character.

(Same goes for character `2` also actually).

Answer (score 0):

You are probably misunderstanding the value as a numeric value, and this value as a printable character.

For example, x has value 2:

```
char ch = 7 - 5;
```

... but ch is the non-printable character 2. If you want the value in ch to be printable, then you must add it again the value of '0'.

```
char ch = x + '0';
```

If the value goes beyond 9, then a more complex algorithm must be used, in order to convert a number to a string.

Answer (score 0):

The format string `"%.*s"` requires two arguments. The first, an `int`, for the minimum width to print (which is `index` (zero) in your case) and the second, a `char*`, for the data itself.

Conclusion: the program is behaving correctly by printing zero characters.